# Texiteasy doesn't generate pdf file

Tags: pdftex, texlive-2017

I have installed Arch Linux on my laptop. I installed `texlive-most`, `texlive-lang` and `texiteasy` *packages* from console and `AUR` of Arch linux. Although `TexitEasy` builds successfully but I don't know why it doesn't generate pdf file.

I get ... :

> "File not found"

Is there anyone help me to solve this problem?
Thank you in advance.
Hoang An

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! With a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), we can check  or try to reproduce your problem. If the code is correct you have to check your installation.

Comment: @Bobyandbob. Hello. Thank you for your reply. I am sure that my code is correct because I have built it successfully several times. Because I get some problems with my OS, I installed Arch Linux again, and then I installed packages by using commands

> "sudo pacman -S texlive-most texlive-lang"
and 
> "yaourt -S texiteasy"

but still not create pdf file

Comment: Hello everyone. I tried to copy to a new file and it works well. I don't know why I got this error?  So, I mark this topic as closed.

Thank you for your support.